# How to update kernel and which version do I need to update to to fix usb driver

Tags: debian, kernel, usb, raspberry-pi

I have a problem with the usb driver for my serial port. In the kernel version that I am on (5.15.32-v8+) the driver does not work. It does work on an earlier 5.10.x that was installed as part of Raspberry Pi Os Buster but on the latest (bullseye) it does not work.

It seems this was discussed [here](https://lore.kernel.org/linux-usb/YZytZ%2FvRioINvb14@hovoldconsulting.com/T/) and presumably a fix put in place. According to [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-signed-hwe-5.13/+bug/1959110) discussion [this](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=aa5721a9e0c9fb8a4bdfe0c8751377cd537d6174) is the commit that fixes the issue.

So I need to try and figure out which version of the kernel includes that fix and then update the kernel on my raspberry pi to that version.

- How do I find out the version of the kernel that includes that commit?
- How do I update the kernel
- are there any dangers to updating the kernel in my OS install - is it likely to have any damaging effects?

Many thanks

Comment: I am afraid the commit you write about ( aa5721a9e0c9fb8a4bdfe0c8751377cd537d6174 ) is not the one that will fix your trouble since you run 5.15.32 when, according to https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/20211130174059.GA3226251@roeck-us.net/T/ (search for the commit id above) it was merged in 5.15.6 times.

Comment: (con't) : But just have a look to https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/log/drivers/usb/serial/pl2303.c , you'll discover that a bunch of other patches were committed since on the same piece of code (pl2303.c) so with some luck, one could be the one you are looking for. But I cannot help any further.